# Lua argument as string name

Tags: string, lua, arguments

I have a string like this:

```
local tempStr = "abcd"
```

and I want to send the variable which is named as "abcd" to a function like this:

```
local abcd = 3

print( tempStr ) -- not correct!!
```

and the result will be 3, not abcd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with local variables if you use a table instead of a "plain" variable:

```
local tempStr = "abcd"

local t = {}

t[tempStr] = 3

print( t[tempStr]) -- will print 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with variables declared as `local`. Such variables are just stack addresses; they don't have permanent storage.

What you're wanting to do is use the content of a variable to access an element of a table. Which can of course be the global table. To do that, you would do:

```
local tempStr = "abcd"
abcd = 3 --Sets a value in the global table.
print(_G[tempStr]) --Access the global table and print the value.
```

You cannot do that if you declare `abcd` as local.

Comment: Shouldn't the last sentence be "You cannot do that if you declare `abcd` as local"?

Answer (score 1):

The function `debug.getlocal` could help you.

```
function f(name)
    local index = 1
    while true do
        local name_,value = debug.getlocal(2,index)
        if not name_ then break end
        if name_ == name then return value end
        index = index + 1
    end 
end

function g()
    local a = "a!"
    local b = "b!"
    local c = "c!"
    print (f("b")) -- will print "b!"
end

g()
```